# How to make a block take the remaining width with flexbox

Tags: html, css

So I have the layout close to this one:

```
.wrapper
  .flex
    .flex-item.first
    .flex-item.last
      %p
```

and css close to this:

```
.wrapper {
  min-width: 1100px
  max-width: 1300px
}

.flex {
  display: flex
}

.flex-item.first {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
}

.flex-item.last {
  flex-grow: 5
}

p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

and what I am trying to achieve is to make the last flex-item take the remaining width and it works fine, almost ...

If I put a long string in the `paragraph tag`, I expect it to take the width of the parent and if the line is too long, to transfer text to the next line and it works just like that in `Chrome`, but in `Firefox`, this long string makes the second `flex-item` go outside the allowed width, making it more than `1300px` and thus breaking the layout...

PS

1)I tried floating the first item to left and adding overflow to the last item and it worked ok ( not without complications ) but flexbox seems easier to work with, I guess ...

2) The number 5 for flex-grow is random, just made it big enough to make it take the remaining space

Link to Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/afj88pc5/

Comment: Post more code, we need to see it in action, can you make a fiddle?

Comment: added the link to fiddle, try it in Chrome and then in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following css will works:

```
p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Check your updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afj88pc5/1/) here.